# label is not getting value from code behind asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I using java script to load the data show in asp Label. the result will be

> 01/01/2016 12:00 AM - 01/25/2016 12:00 AM

When I try to use asp.net code behind to get the label result by clicking button and showing msgbox result showing me empty.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblreserve1" runat="server"  Visible="true"></asp:Label>
```

code behind

```
 MsgBox(lblreserve1.Text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:Label ID="lblreserve1" runat="server"  Visible="true"></asp:Label>
```

you are trying to get "text" property from an element that does not have "text"

you need to add the property and a value:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblreserve1" runat="server" text="Hello World"  Visible="true"></asp:Label>
```